# Are there ANY USB-C 'splitters' (hubs with multiple USB-C ports) in existence?

Tags: usb

While hubs can be found that adapt USB-C to many USB 3.0 ports, or to mDP etc., it seems there is no product out there that simply turns a single USB-C into two or more USB-C ports? Is there a fundamental reason why this would be impossible to do?

Comment: For a power cable splitter, how about the [MagiDeal 2 in 1 Type C to Dual USB Adapter Power Charger OTG Cable Splitter Adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07DPV5YQD)

Comment: Juiced VertexHUB USB-C 3.1 Gen 2 data and charging hub
[review](https://techfruit.com/2019/06/27/review-juiced-vertexhub-usb-3-1-data-and-charging-hub/) and [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M68BNQQ)

Comment: Nov 2019 there is already a very good device (and expensive also) that has all you've asked for and much more
https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMX12ZM/A/caldigit-ts3-plus-dock?afid=p238%7CstMmQi5RQ-dm_mtid_1870765e38482_pcrid_246386975451_pgrid_46609753141_&cid=aos-us-kwgo-pla-btb-catchall--slid---product-HMX12ZM/A

Comment: Here's a $35 dangle that claims to support 10Gbps data transfer (not sure about power delivery tho) https://juicedsystems.com/products/quadhub-usb-c-4-port-travel-hub?variant=30992701063252

Answer (score 18):

Belkin is selling a product ([USB-C 4-Port Mini Hub](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U090/)) which meets your requirements:

**Input:**

- USB-C

**Output:**

- 2 x USB-C
- 2 x USB-A

Additional info:

- 5Gbps Data Transfer Speeds (shared)
- Powered through USB-C host device
- Tethered Type-C Cable for easy access
- Ultra-portable / Slim design
- Charge peripherals with 900mAh (shared)

Comment: this thing is huge - does anyone make a small simple 1 usb-c male to 2x usb-female?

Comment: pass through which I believe yours has is [very important](http://www.abt.com/product/107588/HyperDrive-Silver-USB-Type-C-5-In-1-Hub-With-Pass-Through-Charging-GN21BSILVER.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=sc&utm_campaign=GN21BSILVER&camptype=cpcUSGooglePLA&kwid=productads-adid^167340466078-device^c-plaid^169261555444-sku^107588-adType^PLA)

Comment: also it doesn't pass power through to the mac - so it's largely useless

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you mean an USB 3.1 hub with USB-C on both ends. Because the USB standard does not support splitters. It always needs a hub. USB charging/power cables are the exception.

Also USB-C refers to the port not the cable itself. For example you can have USB 3.1 cable (with type C connectors) or a Thunderbolt 3 cable.

Trust and Belkin have similar mini hubs:
Trust: [USB TYPE-C 4 PORTS USB3.0 HUB](http://www.trust.com/en/product/20820-usb-type-c-4-ports-usb3-0-hub)

Be aware, both hubs (Trust and Belkin) are USB 3.1 Gen 1 (5 gbps) NOT Gen 2. So far  I haven't seen a Gen 2 (10 gbps) hub

At the moment it is just to early. I can imagine that in the near future many USB 3.1 gen 2 hubs will come to market.

[image]

Comment: any update on the existence of Gen 2 hubs?

Comment: splitter = hub with 2 ports IMHO. It's just semantics. Can this pass power through usb-c - and could it be used to plug in the ASUS MB169C+ monitor whilst powering the 12" MacBook & monitor?

Answer (score 9):

Just because this thread is one of the top google search results for USB-C 3.1 (and USB-C 3.1 gen 2) splitters/hubs and Thunderbolt hubs I want to provide some products that I had to search for for a long, long time.

As Mumblic pointed out the availability for splitters are somewhat limited.
I looked around a bit anyways and found a couple of products (hubs!) that:

1. Feature Thunderbolt 3 Charging for **at least** one device
2. Have **additional USB ports** (C and/or A, at least 3.0)
3. Support **at least** one 60Hz 4k, mostly 60Hz 5k or 2x 4k Monitors and
4. cost under 350 Bucks (urgh..)

Ordered by price (low => high):

1. [CalDigit TS3](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1326935-REG/caldigit_500808_ts3_thunderbolt_3_charging.html)
2. [Elgato Thunderbolt 2 Dock](https://www.amazon.de/Elgato-Thunderbolt-Thunderbolt-2-Kabel-Unterst%C3%BCtzung-Aluminumgeh%C3%A4use/dp/B00PFHLH2I/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1520975034&sr=1-2-fkmr0)
3. [OWCTB3 DK13PSG](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01N51P3BB?ascsubtag=UUimUdUnU44159YYwYwnfww64tffzrw63i&linkCode=g12&creativeASIN=B01N51P3BB&tag=androcentr0a-21)
4. [Belkin 3 m Thunderbolt Express Dock](https://www.amazon.de/Belkin-Thunderbolt-verbindet-Anschl%C3%BCsse-kompatibel/dp/B01M2D4SNT/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1520975105&sr=1-1-fkmr0)

These products are still pretty expensive and for this question searching a USB-C Splitter they may be completely off topic, but given the possibilities they offer I think they may be worth the price.

I have not tested any of this products myself but there are some reviews online.

Comment: The products you shared indeed have 2 USB type-c ports but they are for the Mac which has 2 thunderbold ports. So I don't think there is a problem for a mac where 2 ports can easily be passed on through 2 different cables in a hub.
The problem is when you have only 1 Type-C USB port and you want to split that.
Like I have only 1 USB I would love to split it with a USB for my SSD and anther Type-C For video output too. But I can't find any product that would do that. The ones with a single type C output has only PD.

Answer (score 4):

The answer would be no, there are no USB-C splitters in existence.  Neither are there any USB-(insert connector style here) splitters.

USB cannot be split per se, but hubs can be used to connect multiple USB devices to one USB port.

Comment: Would it be possible to add just a power line to deliver additional power like the ones that come with external portable HDDs?

Comment: Thing is, when I search for USB-C hubs, all I get are USB-A hubs with a USB-C connection to a host. I only get USB-C hubs if I search “USB-C Splitter”. What do I have to search to find a USB-C hub that has no USB-A jacks?

Comment: This does not answer the question. And I would argue that it is incorrect depending on what you interpret a “splitter” to be. The asker is obviously asking for a device that allows you to connect multiple USB-C devices to a single USB-C port.

Comment: Ryan, I disagree.  The answer makes clear some very useful info.

Answer (score 0):

##### USB4 Hubs From Now On

While a few pure USB-C hubs had been available before, the advent of USB4 made the USB-C port mandatory. Therefore any USB4 hub will have multiple USB-C ports.

##### USB Naming Confusion

The decision to make USB-C port mandatory in the USB4 spec had the potential to reduce the USB-C confusion somewhat. But the USB4 spec also makes Thunderbolt support mandatory for USB4 hubs (and only for them), the result is that currently they remain expensive and also advertised as Thunderbolt hubs even if you think you don't need Thunderbolt.

| USB4 Hub Examples | Mfr product # |
| --- | --- |
| OWC Thunderbolt Hub | OWCTB4HUB5P |
| Caldigit Element Hub | 500931 |
| Plugable Thunderbolt 4 and USB4 Hub | TBT4-HUB3C |

##### Scarcity

We are 2021 and across industries, the global the chip shortage is blamed for the unavailability of all kinds of electronics. USB4 hubs are no exception.